# Problems with using TCP/IP with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, tcp

Little backstory:
My VPS server is running a webbased game. (PHP/MySQL)
We also have a fairly popular forums and the database of both programs were on the same server. This server also serves the pages with Apache.

Sometimes when the forums were really busy we were seeing that the busy database affected the game also. So we've put the forum database on another server.
Now the forums are connecting to the other server with a TCP/IP connection.

The results of this were awesome, the average server load dropped a lot and the game was rarely slow.
Sometimes though, we get really high spikes of load and then I see that Apache can't serve PHP pages. MySQL's processlist is empty. A lot of Apache connections are there then (which I can see with server-status or top). The requests are normal and there is no sign of a DDoS. Traffic or CPU is not a lot higher than normal.

[image: Server load]

Graph above show one of these times. Before and after are what the server load is normally.
This occasionally happens right after we put the forum database on the other server.

Any clues where to look? 
Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: increase the amount of remote tcp connections on your forum db server and increase the amount of available and max servers on apache on your primary web server.  ideally move the forums off totally onto a sub domain ie: forums.domain.com and run them off the 2nd vps and have the game purely on the primary.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I've followed your advice and put the forum entirely on the other server. I will monitor now if the high loads will or won't come back.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bot/spider indexing your site. You can check by logging the user-agent string.

You can give bots an indication on how fast they can make requests to your site by adding

```
Crawl-delay: [number]
```

to your `robots.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that there's a trend in there where people access pages with lots of external resources.  External scripts, ajax requests, stylesheets, images, sounds, and sometimes included/required php pages, require new connections.  A quick search revealed a [question along these lines](https://serverfault.com/questions/243151/how-does-apache-creates-a-thread) on ServerFault.  A lot of new threads and/or connections running at once could create problems with memory or connectivity.